# Determine the function is convex function or not?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming

I've got some trouble in determining the function, which contains vectors and matrix, is a convex function or not.

\begin{aligned}\min _{x}k^{T}x\\
s.t. Ax\leq y\end{aligned}

$x$ is $n\times1$ vector, $y$ is $m\times1$ fixed vector and $A$ is $m\times n$ fixed matrix

Is the above problem is ***convex optimization problem***? and why?
For this question, should we have to prove both $k^{T}x$ and $Ax\leq y$ are convex functions? If yes, please tell me the detailed steps.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you know what a linear function is and whether linear functions are convex?

Comment: Actually, I have no idea about this question. I've read some doc related to convex function. However, I totally don't understand what are they talking about

Comment: Hmmm...do you know what the definition of convex function and convex set are? Is this for a homework assignment or for your own personal use?

Comment: In general, you have to show/prove that both objective and constraints are convex.

Comment: I think I know what convex set is, but I am not sure the definition of convex function.
This is a question in my lecture note, something like a small quiz after the lecture.

Answer (score 2):

Guide:

A function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$  is convex if for $\forall \lambda \in (0,1), x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $$f(\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2) \le \lambda f(x_1) + (1-\lambda )f(x_2).$$

Now let $f(x)=k^Tx$, verify that the condition above holds.

Also prove that $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n:Ax \le y\}$ is a **convex set**.

Comment: Would you mind to show me the detailed steps for how to proof it?

Comment: give it a try first and I will help to edit your working? You get to learn more if you give a try. For example, try to write out what is $f(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2)$ first?